# Prevent loading the contents of the hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, hidden, getelementbyid

I have a little problem, I set up a system of hidden div that appear click.

There are in total:

- 6 frames : editable text menu at the bottom right (Notre Collection)
- 7 colors for each : modifiable through small squares of color in the frame
- 2 different angles (when you click on a small square of color, that change the view angle)
- 14 pictures for technical drawings (bottom left square format)

I have more than 100 images to load (!) .

Even optimized (80kb per frame , 200kb per photo shoot, 60kb image for tech drawings), there is a lag of about 4-5 seconds to display all the images on a 20mb ADSL connection because my system (works perfectly with IE 6), load the entire contents of all the hidden div... But it should only load the div:block (so only two div when you click on the collection page) and div:hidden are loaded when they turn into div:block...

Visually part of what happens :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgDs7.png

Here's a small part of the HTML :

```
<div id="passionnee-couleurs">
<a onclick='collectionDiv("passionnee-beige-2");'><img src="../images/collection/ico/couleur-beige-vue.png"></a>
<a onclick='collectionDiv("passionnee-bleue");'><img src="../images/collection/ico/couleur-bleue.png"></a>
<a onclick='collectionDiv("passionnee-ecaille");'><img src="../images/collection/ico/couleur-ecaille.png"></a>
<a onclick='collectionDiv("passionnee-ecaille2");'><img src="../images/collection/ico/couleur-ecaille2.png"></a>
<a onclick='collectionDiv("passionnee-grise");'><img src="../images/collection/ico/couleur-grise.png"></a>
</div>
```

With links to display divs (6 in total):

```
<a onclick="collectionDiv('premiere-beige');cotationsDiv('premiere-cotations');">PREMIÈRE</a>
<a onclick="collectionDiv('passionnee-beige');cotationsDiv('passionnee-cotations');">PASSIONNÉE</a>
```

JS part :

```
function collectionDiv(id)
         {
             document.getElementById('passionnee-beige').style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById('passionnee-beige-2').style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById('passionnee-bleue').style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById('passionnee-bleue-2').style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById('passionnee-ecaille').style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById('passionnee-ecaille-2').style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById('passionnee-ecaille2').style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById('passionnee-ecaille2-2').style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById('passionnee-grise').style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
         }
```

And a small part of the CSS :

```
    /* PASSIONNEE */
    #passionnee-beige {
        position:absolute;
        width:994px;
        height:532px;
        margin:auto;
        display:block;
        background-image:url(../images/collection/montures/passionnee-beige.jpg);
}
     
    #passionnee-beige-2 {
        position:absolute;
        width:994px;
        height:532px;
        margin:auto;
        display:none;
        background-image:url(../images/collection/montures/passionnee-beige-2.jpg);
}
     
    #passionnee-bleue {
        position:absolute;
        width:994px;
        height:532px;
        margin:auto;
        display:none;
        background-image:url(../images/collection/montures/passionnee-bleue.jpg);
}
```

Do not hesitate to ask me if you do not understand everything.

Thank you for your help!

Good evening everyone!

EDIT :
http://jsfiddle.net/dktdesign/2B3Rw/12/

Comment: thank you so much, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to do that... innerHTML?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dktdesign/2B3Rw/12/

Comment: That's right. But the final goal is one text (6 in total) link to change 2 div at the same time (frame + technical drawing). And these 2 div have small buttons to load content in these same div (twisted?). You can have a look on the full page here : http://dktdesign.com/les-ptites-pupilles/site/fr/collection.html

Answer (score 0):

The final goal is one text (6 in total) link to change 2 div at the same time (frame + technical drawing). And these 2 div have small buttons to load content in these same div (twisted?). You can have a look on the full page here :
http://dktdesign.com/les-ptites-pupilles/site/fr/collection.html